# updating fluent nhibernate to 1.4 and nhibernate to 3.3.1 gives error with nhibernate.bytecode.castle

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

updating fluent nhibernate to 1.4 and nhibernate to 3.3.1 gives error with `nhibernate.bytecode.castle`

configuring session factory:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration
            .CurrentSessionContext<TCurrentSessionContext>()
            .Configure()
  .Proxy(p => p.ProxyFactoryFactory<ProxyFactoryFactory>());

        // Taken from the SharpArch.Data.NHibernate.NHibernateSession
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure(configuration)
            .Mappings(m =>
            {
                foreach (var mappingAssembly in mappingAssemblies)
                {
                    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(MakeLoadReadyAssemblyName(mappingAssembly));
                    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly);
                }

                if (autoPersistenceModel != null)
                {
                    m.AutoMappings.Add(autoPersistenceModel);
                }
            })
            .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Need to use `proxyfacotry`? what is the new way to do so ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Castle is the default proxy for NHibernate.  You don't need to specify it in the configuration starting with NHibernate 3.  Just remove the line.

Comment: No, NHibernate 3+ has a builtin proxy generator. It is not from the Castle project. End result is the same though - most users should just remove the configuration.

Comment: I suppose the important point, is that the actual castle bytecode DLL isn't used and can also be removed from the runtime environment.